# Permission denied (publickey) while signing in to AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am using Jenkins to ssh into aws server. I am using `.pem` file to login to the server. I am using the below command. The server is of the instance type `ec2`.

```
+ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ceyeApp.pem ubuntu@server_ip
```

but it throws the following error:

```
+ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ceyeApp.pem ubuntu@server_ip
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Load key "ceyeApp.pem": Permission denied
ubuntu@18.216.231.140: Permission denied (publickey).
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Comment: You can use `ssh -v` to obtain a debug log. It looks like it is saying that the public key for that keypair is not stored in the `/usr/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a permissione problem:

```
Load key "ceyeApp.pem": Permission denied
```

Is the user using this key able to read it?
Assuming the user is 'foobar' and he is the owener of the key, make sure the key can be read only by him:

```
chmod 400 ceyeApp.pem
```

If the problem persists, please issue the command John Rotenstein suggested to have a verbose output of what's happening and figure out what other problem might cause the issue.

Comment: Is that permission same as a+r?

Comment: no: it's the equivalent of "chmod u=r,g=-,o=- ceyeApp.pem"